# Create an "item_list function" that does the following features (PLSQL)

Tags: function, dynamic, plsql

I'm trying to create an `"item_list function"` that does the following features:

1. Assign `TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1` as the DEFAULT value of the `pv_end_date` parameter.
2. Create an `item_rec` record type that mirrors the item_obj object type.
3. Create an `item_cur` system reference cursor that is weakly typed cursor.
4. Create an `item_row` variable of the item_rec data type.
5. Create an `item_set` variable of the item_tab collection type, and create an empty instance of the item_tab collection.
6. Create a stmt string variable to hold a Native Dynamic SQL (NDS) variable.
7. Assign an NDS string to the stmt variable. The string should return the following columns:

   - `item_title` with an alias of `title`
   - `item_subtitle` with an alias of `subtitle`
   - `item_rating` with an alias of `rating`
   - `item_release_date` with an alias of `release_date`

   and the `WHERE` clause should check for an `item_rating_agency` value of MPAA and an `item_release_date` between the:

   - bind variables for the `pv_start_date` and `pv_end_date` values

     8. Open the item_cur system reference cursor with the stmt dynamic statement, and assign the `pv_start_date` and `pv_end_date` variables inside the `USING` clause.
     9. Fetch the `item_cur` system reference cursor into the `item_row` variable of the `item_rec` data type.
     10. Extend space in the `item_set` variable of the `item_tab` collection.
     11. Use a `item_row` variable to create an instance of the `item_set` collection.

I already created a `item_obj` and `item_tab`
Here is the part I need some help with:

```
--create a item_list function
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION item_list
  ( pv_start_date   DATE
  , pv_end_date     DATE )

  RETURN item_tab IS

    /* Declare a record type. */
    TYPE item_rec IS RECORD
    ( title           VARCHAR2(60)
    , subtitle        VARCHAR2(60)
    , rating          VARCHAR2(8)
    , release_date    DATE);

    /* Declare reference cursor for an NDS cursor. */
    item_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;

    /* Declare a customer row for output from an NDS cursor. */
    item_row   ITEM_REC;
    item_set   ITEM_TAB := item_tab();

    /* Declare dynamic statement. */
    stmt  VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
    /* Create a dynamic statement. */

stmt := SELECT 'title,  rating'|| FROM   'item '|| WHERE 'REGEXP_LIKE(release_date,''^.*''||:input||''.*$'')';

    /* Open and read dynamic cursor. */
    OPEN item_cur FOR stmt USING pv_start_date AND pv_end_date;
    LOOP
      /* Fetch the cursror into a customer row. */
      FETCH item_cur INTO item_row;
      EXIT WHEN item_cur%NOTFOUND;

      /* Extend space and assign a value collection. */      
      item_set.EXTEND;
      item_set(item_set.COUNT) :=
        item_obj   ( item_title        => item_title.title
                   , item_subtitle     => item_subtitle.subtitle
                   , item_rating       => item_rating.rating
                   , item_release_date => item_release_date.release_date );
    END LOOP;

    /* Return customer set. */
    RETURN item_set;
  END item_list;
/

--call the customer_list function
desc item_list
```

Comment: Did you complete your question?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't know how to update this thing.